# Does the notation $r^3\propto t^2$ mean the same as $t^2\propto r^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I was recently reading about Kepler's third law of planetary motion. There in two books I saw two different things. In one place it is written $r^3\propto t^2$ and in the other book it as written $t^2\propto r^3$.

Now to see if both was the same thing I did this with an example:

[image]

Thus we see that $B=2A$ and thus $B\propto A$

Also we see A=$\frac12$B and thus $A\propto B$. Thus we see that A $\propto B$ is the same as $B \propto A$.

But how can this be? If $A\propto B$ then A=kB and K= $\frac AB$ and if $B\propto A$ then B=kA and $k= \frac {B}{A}$. Thus the value of the constant changes.

I am confused about this. Please help and tell me whether $r^3\propto t^2$ is same as $t^2\propto r^3$.

Comment: $a\propto b$ just means that the ratio is a (non-zero) constant, whatever the constant. Obviously, $a\propto b\implies b\propto a$, with the inverse constant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thant's my point...**inverse constant**....if I use the opposite the value of the constant will change and it might lead to errors....

Comment: You are right @tatan but actually, you didn't get Yves Daoust exactly.  I don't know how I can describe the comment of Daoust in a more lucid way but I can try. When we say two variables are directly proportional. We are actually saying it irrelevant to the constant of proportionality. That is, if two variables are proportional, their ratio is constant. Whatever the constant may be. Then certainly, $a \propto b \implies b \propto a$. This doesn't imply $k=k'$. In $C \propto D$, whether you vary C or D, Both are going to vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\propto B$ tells us that as $A$ varies, $B$ also varies in such a way
that the *ratio* of $A$ to $B$ never changes.
But $A\propto B$ says nothing about the *value* of that ratio.
For example, suppose $x = 2y$ and $y = 3z$. 
The statement $x \propto y$ says the ratio
of $x$ to $y$ is fixed and unchanging. This is true.
The ratio of $y$ to $z$ also is fixed and unchanging. It is fixed at
a different value than the ratio of $x$ to $y$, but it is still fixed.
Therefore $y \propto z$.

This works just as well when the two ratios are $2$ and $\frac12$ 
as it does when the ratios are $2$ and $3$.

Another way to look at this: 
let $A\propto B$, so that $A$ and $B$ vary in such a way
that the ratio of $A$ to $B$ never changes.
If the ratio of $A$ to $B$ never changes, the ratio of $B$ to $A$ cannot change.
Therefore $B \propto A$.

So in fact it really does not matter whether you write $A\propto B$
or $B \propto A$. They mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

$A\propto B$ means that there exists a nonzero constant $k$ with $A=kB$.
$B\propto A$ means that there exists a nonzero constant $k'$ with $B=k'A$ (we are forced to call it $k'$ this time because it certainly is allowed to be a different constant than the $k$ from the first sentence; after all the name of the constant does not matter).
But (using $k\ne 0$ and $k'\ne 0$) by simple reordering of the equation we have $A=kB\iff B=\frac1k A$ as well as $B=k'a\iff A=\frac1{k'}B$. Hence, as we can choose $k'=\frac 1k$ if we are givren $k$, or vice versa pick $k=\frac1{k'}$ if we are given $k'$, we conclude $$ A\propto B\iff B\propto A.$$

Maybe compare with this: An integer $n$ is called *even* if there eixts an integer $k$ with $n=2k$. So is $42$ even? Yes, because we can pick $k=21$ and then have $42=2\cdot 31$. And is $100$ even? Yes, because we can pick $k=50$ and then have $100=2\cdot 50$. Here, too, we have *"Thus the value of the constant changes."* without that it matters.